# How to restore original sort order of NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have tokenized an NSString into an NSMutable Array. I can then use an NSSortDescriptor to sort that array by the length of its strings. Then I can perform methods on certain words starting from the longest.

This is where my problem surfaces. I now need to restore the original sort order of the array so that I can run the array back into an edited string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is essentially like Steve's except that I'd do it the other way around — keep the original array, create a sorted copy of that, step through the sorted copy doing your processing and then throw it away. So, e.g.

```
NSArray *yourOriginalArray = ...whatever...;

// do processing
for(id object in [yourOriginalArray sortedArrayUsing<whatever means>])
{
    // if you're doing processing that doesn't change the identity of
    // the object then there's no need to worry about this, but supposing
    // you want to adjust the identity (eg, the source array is full of
    // immutable objects and you want to replace them) then...

    NSUInteger originalIndex = [yourOriginalArray indexOfObject:object];

    id replacementObject = [self mutatedFormOf:object];
    [yourOriginalArray replaceObjectAtIndex:originalIndex
                     withObject:replacementObject];
    // of course, this is only if yourOriginalArray is mutable
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I think this is just what I needed to get past my hurdle.

Answer (score 2):

The NSMutableArray doesn't know anything about it's previous state only it's current state. There are probably more elegant solutions but one thing you could do is create another array that stores the original sort order.